# How to Blindly Parse in TinyXML

Tags: xml, tinyxml

my XML knowledge is enough to get by.

What I want to do is blindly parse an XML string and get all of the elements and attributes starting at the root. I can't use recursion like the example in the documentation and I can't seem to grasp how to do it with a loop. I know enough to get the root from the XML string and can loop through the string, but can't seem to get the attributes or text values.

I do not know any names of any tags and need to figure them out as I parse. Anyone have any idea how I start or an example?

Thanks

Here is the code I have so far for a XML string like this, works unless its nested elements like the location and country:

```
    string strData = "<MyStuff mystring1=""111"" mystring2=""223"">\
                      <MYTAG1>0</MYTAG1>\
                      <MYTAG2>0</MYTAG3>\
                      <MYTAG4>0</MYTAG4>\
                      <location><country>GreatBritain</country></location>\
                      </MyStuff>";

void parseXmlString2( TiXmlNode* root )
{
TiXmlNode*         child;
TiXmlElement*      elem = (TiXmlElement*)root;
TiXmlAttribute*  pAttrib = elem->FirstAttribute();

//This gets the root and its attributes.
while(pAttrib)
{
    cout << "Value: " << pAttrib->Name() << ":" << pAttrib->Value() << endl;
    pAttrib=pAttrib->Next();
}

//Now I want to parse up the rest.
//Does not work if nested such as <location><country>GreatBritain</country></location>
for( child = root->FirstChild(); child; child = child->NextSibling() )
{

    //Test For child.
    if(child->FirstChild())
    {
        //My helper fuct to tell type
        //getType(child->FirstChild()->Type());
        TiXmlNode*         myChild;
        for( myChild = child->FirstChild(); myChild; myChild = child->IterateChildren(child->FirstChild()))
        {
            cout << " " << myChild->Value() << endl;

        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately this worked for me, thanks to everyone for the input:

```
for( child = root->FirstChild(); child; child = child->NextSibling() )
{

    if(child->Type() == TiXmlNode::TINYXML_ELEMENT)
    {

        thevalue = child->Value();
    }

    //If this Node has children traverse them.
    //and keep going for all.
    if(child->FirstChild())
    {
        TiXmlNode*  myChild  = child->FirstChild();
        while(myChild)
        {


            if(myChild->Type() == TiXmlNode::TINYXML_ELEMENT)
            {

                thevalue = child->Value();
            }

            if(myChild->Type() == TiXmlNode::TINYXML_TEXT)
            {

                thevalue= myChild->Value();
            }
            myChild  = myChild->FirstChild();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got you right. But if you already achieved looping through the XMLElements of your document without recursion then looping through the XMLAttributes should be easy.

Say you have your `XMLElement* elem` you want to obtain the attributes from simply do

```
XMLAttribute* attrib;
for( attrib = elem->FirstAttribute(); attrib != NULL; attrib = attrib->Next() ) {
    // do something
    std::cout << attrib->Name() << " " << attrib->Value();
}
```

Just to see if TinyXML2 does everything right I wrote the following primitive, recursive function which prints out all elements and their attributes (without values):

```
void printAllChildren( XMLElement* parent, int recursionlvl ) {
    std::stringstream indent("");
    for( int i = 0; i <= recursionlvl; i++ ) {
        indent << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "Element Name: " << indent.str() << parent->Name() << " ";
    const XMLAttribute* attrib;
    for( attrib = parent->FirstAttribute(); attrib != NULL; attrib = attrib->Next() ) {
        std::cout << attrib->Name() << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    XMLElement* childEl;
    for( childEl = parent->FirstChildElement(); childEl != NULL; childEl = childEl->NextSiblingElement() ) {
        printAllChildren( childEl, recursionlvl + 1 );
    }
}
```

Hope that helps. Cheers.

EDIT: Without the applications actual output it's hard to guess where the error lies. But shouldn't it be

```
for( myChild = child->FirstChild(); myChild; myChild = child->IterateChildren( child ) )
```

in your most inner loop? (see [a TinyXML Reference](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlNode.html#8621196ba3705fa226bef4a761cc51b6))

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, I'm not at the machine I was working on for this, but I thought when I tried this, it viewed everything as a node and skipped the text and attributes.

Comment: No, this gives me the same result, what I want to do it, parse an XML string without knowing whats in it, and list all the node, attributes, text. I'm not sure if I can do this with one loop or nested loops?

Comment: I can see how to iterate over almost everything, my problem is trying to use the IterateChildren, its seems to crash,but I'm not sure how I'm abusing it.

Comment: Since not all children of TiXMLNode have attributes you have to check if the corresponding node is an TiXMLElement, cast it to that class and eventually loop through the attributes. An example where exactly your application crashes and what you have achieved so far would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I will post what I have, I almost have what I want except for nested elements like this: <location><country>GreatBritain</country></location>

Comment: To your EDIT, I thought that as well, but it doesn't work. I'm getting by with what I have but its not exactly correct and I'm not sure why. I really need it to be less specific of a parse the way I have it, but with TinyXml there is like one example and its recursive.